# 3 mo. old dachshund puppy is quiet in crate for an hour, then starts barking

Tags: dogs, vocalizations, crate, dachshunds

Our 3 mo. old dachshund puppy has gotten pretty good at being in his crate for about an hour to an hour and a half during the day. We've never had any trouble at night. He'll sleep 8+ hours and doesn't whine in the morning, he just waits until we let him out. During the day I've recorded him many times while away to see how he gets on. He'll sometimes whine/bark within the first 5-10 minutes of me putting him in the kennel and leaving, but then he quiets down for at least an hour. Then he'll start whining and barking, and will continue until let out(as long as 40 minutes of barking based on my recordings). I know I've accidentally rewarded it before by thinking he was being quiet when I came home, and then realizing from hearing the recording that he was barking/whining until he heard me coming.  It's frustrating because he's so good for up to an hour and a half. I suspect he sleeps for that first hour to an hour and a half, and then starts barking and whining when he wakes up. What should I do? If I can approach quietly and hear him barking should I wait it out even if he goes on for at least an hour? I don't know yet how long before he'll stop again, or if he even will.

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I teach my puppy to not bark when we leave the room?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10306/how-can-i-teach-my-puppy-to-not-bark-when-we-leave-the-room)

Comment: @AllisonC That question seems quite different, because our dog has little trouble seeing me leave and quieting down. It's only after about a 90 minute threshold that he begins barking/whining. I don't know how to approach correcting what happens beyond the 90 minutes.

Comment: Seems like natural behavior. I wouldn't suggest to prolong his suffering by waiting for him not to bark even when you're finally coming home. I would focus on relieving his isolation and boredom while you're gone by things like (a) smart toys - some have timers and break up the schedule by playing treat-based games intermittently (b) hiring a walker/sitter to check-in midday (c) anxiety vests or pheromone-containing toys (d) playmates (e) not being gone as long or coming home on your lunch break (f) more exercise before you leave him alone.